# Side effects of removing ".terraform" folder

Tags: terraform

According to the documentation, `.terraform` folder contains the cache for the provider's plugins.

If this folder is deleted (but the state file is kept), will it be recreated on `terraform init`?
What are the possible unwanted effects of deleting `.terraform`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `.terraform` directory contains a few different kinds of artifact, some of which track local settings that are only relevant to your current working directory, while others are caches of data from elsewhere.

Broadly-speaking `terraform init` can recreate *most* things in the `.terraform` directory, but there are some small exceptions to be aware of:

- Unless your Terraform configuration contains only local modules or has exact version constraints for remote modules, `terraform init` won't necessarily select the same version of each external module, if the available versions upstream have changed. The `.terraform/modules/modules.json` file (in current Terraform versions) tracks the specific selections in your current working directory.
- If you've selected a non-default [workspace](https://www.terraform.io/language/state/workspaces) using `terraform workspace select`, deleting the `.terraform` directory will reset back to the default workspace because Terraform uses a file under `.terraform` to track your current selection.
- If you used the `-backend-config` option when using `terraform init` then deleting `.terraform` will discard those custom settings, and you'll need to re-specify the same settings when you run `terraform init` again.

The other main artifacts Terraform tracks in `.terraform` are derived from information outside of `.terraform` and so reproducible:

- If you *don't* use `-backend-config` then your backend configuration lives in your `backend` block in your configuration, and so Terraform will be able to reproduce it exactly as long as you haven't changed the configuration.
- The local provider cache in `.terraform/providers` is indexed by [the dependency lock file](https://www.terraform.io/language/files/dependency-lock), which is generated alongside rather than inside `.terraform` so that it can be saved in version control and be shared between working directories. `terraform init` will, by default, install exactly the same dependencies recorded in that file.

The above is true as of Terraform v1.0 and v1.1. The exact contents and layout of `.terraform` are an implementation detail of Terraform and so older versions treat it differently and newer versions may not necessarily follow exactly what I described above.

Answer (score 3):

It is totally safe to delete the `.terraform` directory.
The directory  (`./modules`) and binaries of providers (`./providers`)

```
./
./modules           --> contains the code of used modules
./providers         --> contains the binaries of the providers
./terraform.tfstate --> the state file
```

As follow up to Jason's answer, the result of deletion of the terraform.tfstate file depends whether you're using a backend or not.

If you are using a [backend](https://www.terraform.io/language/settings/backends) (which is the recommended way to save your state file) the next `terraform init` will create a file that points to the state file.

Answer (score 1):

If you delete the the .terraform folder you are correct the providers are deleted but you need to take a back up of the state file as I have seen a couple times that file sometimes gets deleted or corrupted.

A terraform init does bring .terraform folder back.

Why do you need to do this? As you can run terraform init -reconfigure and that is a safer option.